# Maintain Consistency in Microservices

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, consistency

Our system composed by microservices and using rabbit-mq for event-driven architecture. Said that i have 2 services, Service-A and Service-B. Service-B subscribes for event 'product-purchased'. Here are what happens when someone purchase a product in our system:

1. Purchasing transaction recorded in db by Service-A.
2. After transaction successfuly recorded by Service-A, then Service-A will publish event 'product-purchased'.
3. Once Service-B receives event 'product-purchased', it will update the inventory in db.

My question is what happen when step 3 is failed. How to maintain the consistency?

Comment: Why did you put step 3 as the last? It is the first in the timeline.

Comment: actually, before step 1 and 2 begin, Service-B will listen or subscribe for event 'product-purchased'. The actual logic in Service-B only be executed after step 1 and 2 done.

Comment: So you should edit your question to reorder the steps. Put item no. 3 as being no. 1

Comment: i changed the question as you wish

Comment: Why did step 3 failed? It could be retried, it could be sent to a DLQ for someone to manually fix the problem, etc, etc, etc. You would need a more detailed scenario, otherwise the question is too open for discussion.

Comment: What happens if step 2 fails?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo i.e. server is restarted/powered down/power failure  exactly before step 3.

Comment: If you're using queues, as you said, there is no reason to lose message simply because a server was down or temporarily unreachable. The messages can be kept in the queue and consumed when the service is back up again.

Comment: You should specify the degree of integrity which you need on the microservice integration level. Loosely connected services may be able to live with queues and a mechanism to be notified about events they missed in the past. But if the item can suddenly be out of stock due to some irregularity, someone who paid may not be amused. From the description, it's not clear what exactly happens when. Two-Phase Commits may be necessary here. In this regard, the "duplicate" is not really helpful.